# Do I need to have a BIS or BES service in order to use MapField in the code?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-storm

I am trying to learn about MapField in Blackberry and I need to know that wheter I need to have a BIS or BES service in order to use MapField. I can use the MapFiel while using the simulator but when I read some forums I saw some people wrote that people need to have BIS or BES to show the MapField. Is it true or not ?

Thank you all...

Comment: They sure need an internet connection. Whether it's Wifi or 3G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a BIS conection, so you should run the MDS emulator to have the BIS server emulation on your computer, this will work for your mobile simulator. The MDS emulator can be downloaded at blackberry official web page at developement tools.