# blackberry Mapfield and RichMapField show blank page

Tags: blackberry, bitmapfield

I want to create a map field into my blackberry app using java eclipse, I create a map field and RichMapField and both shows blank page.

Note that my device does not contains a sim card, please can anyone helps me

Comment: use third party maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, BB maps requires BIS to be enabled. And since you don't have a sim in your device, I'd rate thats the problem.

[Do I need to have a BIS or BES service in order to use MapField in the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304066/do-i-need-to-have-a-bis-or-bes-service-in-order-to-use-mapfield-in-the-code)

I find this to be really silly and kind of unacceptable, so depending on your requirements, I'd consider Google Maps instead.

[Use Google Map in Blackberry application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387688/use-google-map-in-blackberry-application)

[Bing Maps SDK For Blackberry 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977201/bing-maps-sdk-for-blackberry-6-0/9987588#9987588) (Accepted answer is an example of using Google Maps installed on the device)

Comment: Thank you its really help :) i would try to create a browser field inside the app and create the map using javascript