# how to create map in blackberry using browser field and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, blackberry

i create a html file that show a google map using javascript i tried it on chrome and firefox and its working, now i want to show the map into my blackberry app so i put it into eclipse and create a browserfield that show the content of this html file, but when i open the app it show blank, the map does not appear

this is the code of map in javascript:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    AIzaSyBxGIma4VDwwcvBjgqLkfDLTxHFVV1mGd8">
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
```

and this is the code how i show the browser field in blackberry

```
        BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);

             InputStream content =    getClass().getResourceAsStream("/map.html");     
             try {
                   byte[] html = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(content);
                   String htmltxt = new String(html);

                 browserField.displayContent(new String(htmltxt),  "local:///");


             } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075497/blackberry-mapfield-and-richmapfield-show-blank-page) you asked about this, I linked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387688/use-google-map-in-blackberry-application/1531216#1531216) to you. Max said it's not possible because of poor Javascript support in BrowserFields.

This [post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Google-Maps-Javascript-API-v3-and-BlackBerry/td-p/255021) suggests that it's because the browerfield does not support AJAX (which I am inclined to believe). The final post on that link does claim to have it working, albeit with an inconsistent map marker. It's worth a try, but other than that you'll need to either use static maps, or launch the google maps app.

Comment: sorry but this is not true, i have already display a map into browser field but the map was located on server with javascript and jquery and i show the map using browser field like this 
   BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
         myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
         BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);

      //   add(browserField);
         browserField.requestContent("link of the map");